# Google Cloud CloudSQL Cloning

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, cloud, clone, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to find more information on GCP CloudSQL Cloning feature but can't find good enough info anywhere or in google docs.
Is this feature similar to zero copy clones which will make instant clones of databases, or it does physical copy of blocks from one instance to create new Cloud SQL instance?

I have 10 TB of postgres database and wondering what's the best way to make a copy of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already checked this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/instances/clone)?

Comment: Yes @MarcAnthonyB I did, but this documentation doesn't have any details on how cloning really works.